# The existence of a limit

Tags: limits

Just need some clarification on the existence of a limit theorem.
I'm going to use a really simple function f(x) = x to demonstrate my confusion

I know that lim of x as x approaches to zero is 0 because of 2 major reasons:
1) f(0) = 0 is defined at x = 0
2) lim of x as x approaches to zero is zero, which is equal to f(0)

Here is where I am confused. In order for a limit of a function to equal L, the left and right limits must also equal L.

The limit of x as x approaches from the left of zero seems to produce difference values that limit of x as x approaches from the right of zero.
For example, if I pick -.001 for numbers left of zero, then it'll approach -.001. However, if I pick .001 for numbers right of zero, then it'll approach .001.
Am I missing something? I feel like I may be over-complicating this, but could someone just explain to me why my thought process here is incorrect?

Comment: You have six questions but you haven't accepted any answers, you may want to take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks Micheal. Will start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're missing is that you can approach the value $zero$ with any level of precision from any direction. You don't need to stop at neither $-0.001$ nor at $0.001$; the point is that you can get as close as you want (in terms of absolute difference of values) . You can choose to approach closer using the values , say, $0.00001$ and $-0.00001$, and you can increase precision  by as much as you want; both values can be made to be indefinitely-close to the value $0$ by choosing $x$ as close as $0$ as you want(maybe the case of $f(x)=x$ is somewhat tautological). This last idea is made more precise\rigorous using the layout of $\delta - \epsilon$; here $\epsilon$ is the level of precision you want, and $\delta$ tells you "how much" you need to approach (horizontally here ) the argument part for the "output part" to be as close as you want it (close by $\epsilon$). If you can approach the same value from both ends (or, in higher dimensions, from all possible directions), then the limit exists, even if this limit does not equal the value of the function at the point. Take the function $f(x)=-1$ if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x>0$. The limit at $0$ does not exist, because the functional values from the left and right will not be indefinitely close to each other, and so cannot be indefinitely-close to a possible limit value.

Comment: So you're saying the signs don't necessarily matter because we're only interested in the distance?

Comment: Yes, exactly, tho zero is a special case.

Comment: That actually makes sense (especially thinking about the epsilon-delta definition). Thanks, user99680! Appreciate you helping me twice tonight :)

Comment: Glad to help, Astro, let me know if you have a followup.